# update single object and send through url using spring

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

home.jsp

```
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${dataList}">

    <tr>
     <td>
     <input type="text"  value="${row[0]}" readonly/>
    </td> 
    <td>
         <input type="text"  value="${row[1]}"/>
    </td>
    <td>
         <input type="text"  value="${row[2]}"/>
    </td>
    <td>
         <input type="text"  value="${row[3]}"/></td>
    <td>
         <input type="text"  value="${row[4]}"/>
    </td>
    <td>
         <input type="text"  value="${row[5]}"/>
    </td>
    <td>
         <input type="text"  value="${row[6]}"/>
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href="edit" ><input type="button" value="Update"></a>
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href="delete"><input type="button" value="Delete"></a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

[image: Updates and deletes employees]

I want data of only edited employee to controller,not all employees,tried every annotation.please sugguest the best way to get it to controller

MyController code

```
@RequestMapping("/edit")
    public ModelAndView editEmployee(@RequestParam(value="employee") Employee emp) {

        System.out.println(emp);
        List dataList =service.editEmployee(emp);
        if(dataList.equals("")|| dataList.equals(null))
        {
            mav.addObject("msg", "Failed to edit data");
            mav.setViewName("home");

        }

        else
        {

            mav.addObject("dataList",dataList);
            mav.setViewName("home");
        }
        return mav;
    }
```

I want the edited employee data in the request param..what could be the best way to send the data through url.I have a model Class for Employee for inputs

Comment: The suggested answer is not going to help you. You annotation you need is @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee. You will need a separate form per employee rather than 1 for the whole table. There are any number of tutorials that show you basic binding works in Spring MVC. For example: https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-mvc%E2%80%99s

Comment: I'm aware of the @ModelAttribute.The thing is i don't want an separate form for editing and update every employee for a  single employee edit.I only want the edited employee to be updated using HibernateTemplate.update(emp). Any solution??

Comment: In would suggest reading the Spring MVC manual and understanding the fundamentals. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller

Answer (score 1):

First you have to populate the Employee Object with employee Id which one you want to update, then update it. Pass the employee Id from jsp to controller and use PathVariable in controller

```
@RequestMapping("/edit/{employeeId}")
public ModelAndView editEmployee(@PathVariable Long employeeId, @RequestParam(value="employee") Employee emp) {
    emp = employeeDAO.findbyQuery("findByEmployeeId", employeeId).get(0);
    System.out.println(emp);
    List dataList =service.editEmployee(emp);
    if(dataList.equals("")|| dataList.equals(null))
    {
        mav.addObject("dataList",dataList);
        mav.setViewName("home");
    }

    else
    {
        mav.addObject("msg", "Failed to edit data");
        mav.setViewName("home");
    }
    return mav;
}
```

Comment: But will the populated Employee Object will contain the edits made to the object in controller?? @suman behara

Comment: if your using spring form in jsp then Employee Object will contain the edits made to the object in controller

Comment: But im using html inputs and sending via url not submit.What could be a possible way out to get the edited object.I don't want a new jsp for editing

Comment: I think this may helps u try it. small change in your jsp.pass the employee id in <c:url />tag.
<c:url value='/employee/edit/${employeeId}' var='editEmployeeObjectURL'/>
<a href="${editEmployeeObjectURL}"><input type="button" value="Update"></a>